# Is SQL Server 2000 Free?

Tags: sql, sql-server, licensing

Is SQL Server 2000 Free? I mean, can I use it for commercial use like SQL Server 2005 Express Edition?

Comment: For distribution, or just use?

Comment: As far as I know: NO! It's still a commercial product - you cannot buy it anymore, but that doesn't imply that it's FREE

Comment: Brad's question is a non-starter.  It doesn't matter if it's personal use, in an application that's distributed, or in any other form.  It's not free

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't. You need to purchase licenses if you want to develop and deploy using it.

There are no Express versions of SQL Server 2000 either.

There are Express editions of SQL Server 2005 and 2008/R2 - these are free.

Comment: ok, thanks for that information. I'm just wondering if I can use this old installer of SQL Server 2000 that I have.

Comment: MSDE was the free version of SQL 2000.

Comment: If you have a valid 2000 install that isn't being used elsewhere then there is no reason you can't install it.

Comment: @lazyDBA - Only if it indeed valid and has a valid license.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not free, I'm not sure you can use express edidtion for commercial use can you?

have you considered an open source database like MySQL?

Comment: Express CAN be used for commercial purposes.  Lot's of applications run on express.

Comment: You can use express edition for commercial use (http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express.aspx), and there is a SQL Server express equivalent for SQL Server 2000, and it is called MSDE (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSDE), no longer supported I believe.